# Favoritar imovel/produto com session/cookies utilizando php

Tags: php

Como é desenvolvido aplicações que dá opção ao usuário de adicionar imóveis/produtos a uma lista de favoritos com session/cookies utilizando php sem banco de dados?

Answer (score 0):

Se não quiser usar banco de dados, terá de salvar em outro local que permite consultas futuras, como arquivos ou cookies.

O risco de salvar em cookies é que eles são transferidos em todas as requisições HTTP. Ou seja, se salvar muitos dados nos cookies, o cabeçalho HTTP ficará grande e as requisições ficarão demoradas.

O ideal seria salvar apenas um identificador do usuário no cookie e manter o IDs dos imóveis no servidor, seja em banco de dados ou em arquivos

Comment: Vc tem um exemplo de como ficaria essa aplicação?